# WinUI3 build started failing randomly giving a odd error about resources.pri

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've been working on a new WinUI3 app in visual studio, and it has been building and debugging perfectly, until at some point I probably changed some setting unknowingly and haven't been able to build since..

> Error     DEP1000: Cannot copy file "C:\Users\derek\source\repos\DerekSmartChain\DerekSmart\bin\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\resources.pri" to layout "C:\Users\derek\source\repos\DerekSmartChain\DerekSmart\bin\x64\Debug\resources.pri". DirectoryNotFoundException - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\derek\source\repos\DerekSmartChain\DerekSmart\bin\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\resources.pri'. [0x80070003]  DerekSmart

This 'resources.pri' file that it's trying to copy doesn't exist in the folder its referencing, or anywhere in '/bin/'

I don't see anything online about this.. I hope someone knows what's going on here.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure this out, but recreating the project fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error, the file you referenced and copied in the program does not exist, it may be that the program was not created correctly when it was run.

It causing this replication error.

Caused [EDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/data-execution-prevention) problem.

In this case, we can generally try to clean the project first and then rebuild or recreate this project.

So the solution to solve the problem is to recreate the project.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I deploy a Windows application, but this application is already running and DevTools is open in it.

You need to close DevTools